# Image & text in left and right side on alternate row in ListView JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

```
    ListView<ChatModel> listView;
ObservableList<ChatModel> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

private final Image IMAGE_MEN = new Image("men.png");
private final Image IMAGE_WOMEN = new Image("women.png");

private Image[] listOfImages = {IMAGE_MEN, IMAGE_WOMEN};

listView = new ListView<ChatModel>();
        listView.setPrefHeight(550);
        listView.setItems(items);

        listView.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<ChatModel>() {
            private ImageView imageView = new ImageView();

            @Override
            public void updateItem(ChatModel name, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(name, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    if (name.getClientName().equals("testing"))
                        imageView.setImage(listOfImages[0]);
                    else if (name.getClientName().equals("testing1"))
                        imageView.setImage(listOfImages[1]);
                    setText(name.getClientMessage());
                    setGraphic(imageView);
                }
            }
        });
```

I, am using the above code to add the item in the listview using image and text it works fine but the design in list view are in left side in all the rows. I, have a requirement that the alternate row should have different design. The next row should have right side element.

Here is the design as I have achieved till now

[image: image of list view]

I want the alternate row in left and right side.

Please anyone can tell me how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it with CSS:

```
.list-view .list-cell:odd {
    -fx-content-display:left;
}

.list-view .list-cell:even {
   -fx-content-display:right;
}
```

The selectors set the `-fx-content-display` property based on the pseudo-state of the `ListCell`:

- `odd`: text left - graphic right
- `even`: grahic left - text right

Comment: How can I set it. I tried listView.getStylesheets().add("list-view"); but it didn't work

Comment: In the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm), section "Creating Style Sheets". E.g. if you have an `app.css` beside your `Application` source, then you can call: ` `scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("app.css").toString());`

Comment: scene.getStylesheets().add("ChatStyle.css"); & listView.getStyleClass().add("list-view"); I tried but not working for me

Comment: `listView.getStyleClass().add("list-view");` is not needed. `scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("ChatStyle.css").toString());` should work.

Comment: Why select `ListCell`s only if there is a node between it and the `ListView` in the scene graph? Space is used as descendant selector in css and should work fine in this case: `.list-view .list-cell:odd`, `.list-view .list-cell:even`